# Conflict with kube-prometheus when installing metric-server

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kube-prometheus-stack

I use AWS EKS environment, and I have https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus installed for monitoring. I'd like to get autoscaler installed where one of the prerequisites is https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server.

I first did

`kubectl diff -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml`

just to understand the diffs before applying. Then I find `kube-prometheus` and `metrics-server` conflict in two places:

1. `apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io`
   [image]
2. `clusterrole/system:aggregated-metrics-reader`
   [image]

My questions are:

What are my options if I'd like to get `metric-server` installed along with `kube-prometheus`? Should I override or merge? Is that a bad idea?

Thanks!